# Increasing size of image on click JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm having a problem with my click function in Jquery. Basically, I have a row of products and on hover(using CSS), I Have an effect which enlarges the image. Now, I made a click function in JQuery such that on selecting a product, the selected image stays bigger than the rest and when I select another product, the previously enlarged image goes back to normal.

Now I have written a few lines of code but can't get it right. I am assuming there is some sort of conflict between the hover and the click function but I can't figure out how to fix it.

Here's a JSFiddle link(All the codes are there. I added the JQuery below):

https://jsfiddle.net/svjyqva5/

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    //Select Item
    $(".anItem").click(function(){  
        // $(".anItem").each(function() {
        //      $(this).removeClass("selectedItem");
        // });

        if($(this).hasClass("selectedItem")){
            $(this).removeClass("selectedItem");
            itemColor = "";
        }else{
            itemColor = $(this).data("color");
            $(this).addClass("selectedItem");
    //      $("#oneBtn").show();
        }                       
    });
});
```

Would appreciate some help.

Comment: Change the `width: 220px;` to `transform: scale(1.25);` on your `selectedItem` class

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change this in your CSS:

```
.anItem:not(.selectedItem):hover{
    -webkit-transform: scale(1.25); 
    -moz-transform: scale(1.25);
    -o-transform: scale(1.25);
    transform: scale(1.25);
}

.selectedItem {
  -webkit-transform: scale(1.25);
  -moz-transform: scale(1.25);
  -o-transform: scale(1.25);
  transform: scale(1.25);
}
```

And in your JS add:

```
$(".anItem").not(this).removeClass("selectedItem");
```

at the beginning of your click-handler.

---

[Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/m89cfa7b/2/)

Comment: Not sure if this will work 100% as the image should revert back when clicked after it already has the `selectedItem` class.

If you remove the `selectedItem` class at the start of the click handler it will just re add it

Comment: @nTuply then its all good, just seemed that you were aiming to remove the class when clicked a second time :)

Comment: @Bart you're right, I oversaw that. Updated my script. This should now handling the second click correctly.

Comment: @Bart I was aiming for that as well and now that you mention it, I realize it's not working as expected

Comment: Excellent answer. Thanks @empiric :-)

Answer (score 0):

**Logic** -

Apply CSS Transform Scale on selected (`this`) item and remove it from rest (from common class).

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
 //Select Item
 $(".anItem").click(function(){ 
  $(".anItem").css('transform','scale(1)')
  $(this).css('transform','scale(1.25)');
    
  
  if($(this).hasClass("selectedItem")){
   $(this).removeClass("selectedItem");
   itemColor = "";
  }else{
   itemColor = $(this).data("color");
   $(this).addClass("selectedItem");
 //  $("#oneBtn").show();
  }      
 });
});
```

```css
.orderRow{
 width: 60%;
 /*border: 1px solid #000;*/
 height: 180px;
 margin-top: 20px;
 display: block;
 margin: 0 auto;
 padding-bottom: 10px;
}

.singleItem{
 width: 240px;
 height: 180px;
 float: left;
 /*border: 1px solid #000;*/
}

.lMargin{
 margin-left: 2.7%;
}

.anItem{
 width: 200px;
 height: auto;
 display: block;
 margin: 0 auto;
 cursor: pointer;
}

.anItem:hover{
    -webkit-transform: scale(1.25); 
    -moz-transform: scale(1.25);
    -o-transform: scale(1.25);
    transform: scale(1.25);
}

.anItem{
 -webkit-transition: all .4s ease-in-out;
 -moz-transition: all .4s ease-in-out;
 -o-transition: all .4s ease-in-out;
 -ms-transition: all .4s ease-in-out;
}

.selectedItem{
 width: 220px;
 height: auto;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="orderRow">
                    <div class="singleItem lMargin">
                        <h4>Blue</h4>
                        <img class="anItem" data-color="blue" src="http://bigstartups.co.za/permiclip/website/images/blue.png" />
                    </div>   

                    <div class="singleItem lMargin">
                        <h4>Grey</h4>
                        <img class="anItem" data-color="grey" src="http://bigstartups.co.za/permiclip/website/images/grey.png" />
                    </div>   

                    <div class="singleItem lMargin">
                        <h4>Red</h4>
                        <img class="anItem" data-color="red" src="http://bigstartups.co.za/permiclip/website/images/red.png" />
                    </div>                         
                </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add a class 'active' to clicked element and removed from other element   [fiddile](https://jsfiddle.net/svjyqva5/5/)

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $(".anItem").click(function(){  

  $(".active").removeClass("active");
  $(this).addClass("active");

    });
});
```